# Data microsoft excel transformation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

[image: Data transformation in excel 2010]

Data runs to a thousand rows, please let me know how can I do this?

Comment: Type is constant to three items, viz., PL, CL FL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Pivot Table will help you in this situation:

[image]

Comment: I tried pivot table, but had problem getting content on column 2 of data table (Type) PL, CL, FL to align as column headers

Comment: Thank you very much for the sample, it resolved the issue !!